# Refer all arguments passed at command line from a specific index to the end - batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, args

Let's say I'm passing some arguments from command line to a batch script. 
Like: `myfile.bat flower, tree, doge, cate, house`
But the length of the argument list is dynamic, not 5 all the time. 
How can I get all arguments from n to last.
For example, if n was 2, what should I write in order to get doge, cate, house.
Edit based on comment question.

Comment: What is the real question? Do you want the last `n` arguments, fron `n` to `last` one, or what?

Comment: yes, exactly, from n to last

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a skipargs=2
SET "destvar=somevarname"

CALL :getargs %*

SET somevarname

SET /a skipargs=1
SET "destvar=somevarname"

CALL :getargs %*

SET somevarname


GOTO :EOF

:getargs
IF %skipargs% gtr 0 SET /a skipargs-=1&shift&GOTO getargs
SET "%destvar%="
:getargsl
IF DEFINED %destvar% (CALL SET "%destvar%=%%%destvar%%% %1"
) ELSE (
 SET "%destvar%=%1"
)
SHIFT
IF "%~1" neq "" GOTO getargsl
GOTO :eof
```

This should demonstrate how to assign *all args after the nth* to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using a `for` loop over `%*` (this displays all but the first `_NUMSKIP` arguments):

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "_NUMSKIP=2"
set /A "INDEX=0"
for %%A in (%*) do (
    set /A "INDEX+=1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !INDEX! GTR %_NUMSKIP% (
        endlocal
        echo(%%A
    ) else endlocal
)
```

Note that this is not safe against all strings; for example, an argument `&"&"` causes a syntax error!

---

To collect the remaining arguments in a single line for later transfer to an executable, this helps:

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "_NUMSKIP=2"
set /A "INDEX=0" & set "ARGS= "
for %%A in (%*) do (
    set /A "INDEX+=1"
    set "ARGV=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !INDEX! GTR %_NUMSKIP% (
        for /F "delims=" %%B in (^""!ARGS!!ARGV!"^") do (
            endlocal
            set "ARGS=%%~B "
        )
    ) else endlocal
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!ARGS:~1,-1!
endlocal
```

Note that the original argument delimiters become replaced by a single <kbd>SPACE</kbd> each.

Comment: This parses arguments wrongly, take a look using this `"flower", t;ree, "doge", ca;te, ho=use`. it's output is `ree "doge" ca te ho use` where each space signifies a new line. I however don't expect all answers to work perfectly with any set of unknown input parameters. BTW, the other two answers using n=2 also do not work with the above input either!

Comment: @Compo, the parsing is correct here, the `echo` outputs in separate lines are just to show the arguments; of course they can be recollected into a single variable or output in a single line -- see the [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41018823/2)...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@echo off

set/a skip=1 & rem set skip to the number of arguments to forget
for /L %%i in (1,1,%skip%) do shift & rem skip arguments

:getArg 
echo %~1 & shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto :getArg
exit/B
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -2):

This seems a little simpler, *(for me at least)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "n=2"
For /F "Tokens=%n%*" %%A In ("%*") Do Set "remainder=%%B"
Echo(%remainder%
Timeout -1
```

Change the value of variable n on line two as required

Comment: I'm afraid this parses arguments wrongly as `for /F` does not handle quotation `""` properly; in addition, there the following argument delimiters: *space*, *tab*, `,`, `;`, `=` and the *non-break space* (code `0xFF`)...

Comment: Don't be afraid… My answer works perfectly with the question asked, I even checked the pre-edited version. It should also work perfectly well with `"flower", t;ree, "doge", ca;te, ho=use`. which if I'm not mistaken means that your above comment is completely wrong because it contains both a commas. I accept that there are some scenarios where my answer will not be suitable, but it works 100% within the parameters of the question.

Comment: Your approach parses `"flo wer"` as two separate items -- `"flo` and `wer"`; however, `cmd` regards `"flo wer"` as one argument due to quotation; that is what I was referring to; of course your code works for the example of the question, but it may fail in real-life situations...